# Graph API : Live Event Attedence Report

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-live-meeting

I am trying to get attendence report of a live meeting through Graph API, but it is returning an empty array.I have used both Beta & V1.0. I am not sure what am missing.

I can download the excel file of attedence repot from teams
[image]

please help me out!

[image]

Comment: In the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), it says `Each time an online meeting ends, an attendance report is generated for that session`. So are you sure the online meeting is ended?

Comment: `To use application permission for this API, tenant administrators must create an application access policy and grant it to a user. This authorizes the app configured in the policy to fetch online meetings and/or online meeting artifacts on behalf of that user (with the user ID specified in the request path).` from [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/meetingattendancereport-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: I am using and want to us delegated Permissions, but not application permissions.

Comment: I just want to share what I found in the official api document. .. check the document and validate your scenario. I know it's weird about your issue.